# ios predicate one to many

Tags: ios, core-data, predicate

I have 2 tables in my core data model.

ITEM and FILTER

FILTER has many ITEM

I am trying to fetch all items with parameter of table FILTER, isSelected == 1.

I have this predicate but it is not working, could you please help me how to get my desired items?
I am using MagicalRecord

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"filter.isSelected == 1"];
NSArray *items = [Item MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate];

self.itemList = [items copy];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I am doing same thing for Item and Department in my app.

```
Filter *department=nil;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Filter" inManagedObjectContext:__managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

Item *anItem=nil;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:__managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isSelected==%d and isSelected==%@", [department.isSelected integerValue ], @"1"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSArray *resultSet = [UpdateManager executeForContext:self.managedObjectContext FetchRequest:fetchRequest];
```

resultSet is you result array.

Try and let me know.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way how to do it via MagicalRecord not using fetchRequests ? Or are the Fetchrequests necessary ? OR is there a way how can I jump through relationships like `item.filter.some_parameter` and compare the variables?

Comment: I have not much idea about Magical Record.

Answer (score 2):

You could first fetch all the filters whose `isSelected` value is 1. Then loop through each of them and form and array of the items. Below is the code.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isSelected == 1"];
NSArray *filters = [Filter MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate];
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];
for (Filter *filter in filters)
{
    items = [items arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:filter.items];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the mistake myself, now I know why it gave me an empty array, I haven't set the FILTER object for each created ITEM when I was inserting them into the database :-/ what a stupid mistake. But Both of the above responses seem to work as well. Both + 1, Thanks